# How to recover a git repository that has been corrupted by having line endings changes from CRLF to LF?

Tags: git, line-endings

I changed all of the line endings in my project from dos mode to unix mode by removing all of the carriage returns from any file that had them:

```
grep -lIUr '^M' . | xargs sed -i 's/^M//'
```

I thought that it would ignore hidden dotfiles like `.git/`, but it didn't, and now my git repository has been mangled.

```
git fsck
```

gives

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: loose object 62f7323e2a025640a25214f13a670097876c1683 (stored in .git/objects/62/f7323e2a025640a25214f13a670097876c1683) is corrupt
```

There aren't any other copies of the repository checked out anywhere. Is there any way to recover from this? Is my repo dead?

Comment: Yowch.  Good luck.  I think you're probably SOL, though.  Maybe someone will have a nifty trick for you.

Comment: One can only hope. I will never let a script run loose on a project, without a recent backup, ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. No luck, since all ^M are gone: maybe you can partially recover history and build another repo, but nothing more.

For the future, use greater care and proper tools like `dos2unix` for converting line endings.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about dos2unix. I've never used it, but I have seen it before somewhere. A painful reminder on backups.

Comment: For some reason Ubuntu prefers to call it `fromdos` (comes from package strangely named `tofrodos`) - which is of course equivalent to `dos2unix`

Answer (score 1):

In the future (does not help you now), you can limit your command to files in the repository.

```
grep -lIUr '^M' `git ls-files` | xargs sed -i 's/^M//'
```